# Map using CRS Simple in react-leaflet won't center

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Started using react-leaflet very recently as a possible solution for handling custom image based maps. I'm having an issue where the map won't center on any co-ords I give it when using CRS.Simple, but it seems to work with a standard TileLayer map. The co-ords work correctly with other components, I tested it at [0,0] with a plain circle object.

Any help would be much appreciated! Expecting it to be something silly I've done.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Circle, Map, Marker, TileLayer, Popup, ImageOverlay } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'leaflet'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import icon from '../assets/icons/person.svg';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function LocationHub(props) {

    const personIcon = new L.icon({
        iconUrl: icon,
        iconRetinaUrl: icon,
        iconAnchor: [20, 40],
        popupAnchor: [0, -35],
        iconSize: [60, 60]
    })

    const bounds = [[0, 0], [4734, 7000]]
    const style = { height: '80vh', width: '75vw' }

    return (
        <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center'>
            <Map crs={L.CRS.Simple} center={[0, 0]} minZoom={-2} bounds={bounds} style={style}>
                <Marker icon={personIcon} position={[bounds[1][0] - 1830, 3083]}>
                    <Popup>
                        A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
                <ImageOverlay
                    bounds={bounds}
                    url='https://ddimagecollection.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/maps/PhanDay.jpg'
                />
                <Circle center={[0, 0]} radius={200} fillColor='blue' />
            </Map>
        </Box>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your codepen doesn't seem to be working (it's throwing syntax errors on the `jsx` bits)

Comment: Sorry, should have made it clear the codepen was just to show the code, without a lot of tinkering it won't show correctly.